# Cannot create index on view "dbo.TestMV" because it references an internal SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am seeing this error whilst trying to create an index on a `View` in `SQL Server 2012`:

> Cannot create index on view "dbo.TestMV" because it references an
>   internal SQL Server column?

What kind of object is "an internal SQL Server column"? 
Such entity is not mentioned in the MS documentation or internet.

P.S. There are no system tables in the view' statement.

Comment: Please post your `view definition` and the `create index` statement

Comment: It is huge (several pages) auto-generated view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special columns are columns like the undocumented [`%%physloc%%`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-new-undocumented-physical-row-locator-function/) or [`%%lockres%%`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/investigating-locking-and-deadlocking-with-lockres/) and a couple similar more. They cannot be indexed.

Comment: Yes there is such column in the view (view is huge and generated by SSMA). I do not want to index exactly this column, but it seems that if view has such column, this prevents creation of clustered index.

Comment: BTW. I predict that there should be also row version %%XXX%% system column (row version that used in the snapshot transaction isolation models), is n't it?